# I am new to Python. And this recursive program tends not to run for some strange reason I can't figure out. Any help would be grateful

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

This program is supposed to take in a number and find its reverse. If the number comes out to be a palindrome it prints the number. If the number is not palindrome it adds the number to its reverse and then again checks for palindrome. And this keeps happening which also says that the final result should be a palindrome.
Here is the code:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
def palindromeConverter(n):
    m = n
    rev = 0
    while(n>0):
        rev = (rev*10) + (n%10)
        n = n/10
    if(rev==m):
        return rev
    else:
        return palindromeConverter(rev+m)
print(palindromeConverter(num))
```

Comment: Try splitting this into 2 functions, 1 to find the reverse, and another to check for a palindrome.

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you print *n* you´ll see that your script runs infinite. The while loop never ends

```
while(n>0):
    rev = (rev*10) + (n%10)
    n = n/10
    print(n)
```

### Edit:

After I googled for some examples i think your *n = n/10* division is wrong. It should be a floor division *n = n//10*

If you change it like this, it works well:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
def palindromeConverter(n):
    m = n
    rev = 0
    while(n>0):
        rev = (rev*10) + (n%10)
        n = n//10
    if(rev==m):
        return rev
    else:
        return palindromeConverter(rev+m)
print(palindromeConverter(num))
```

Comment: Also be aware that Python has a relatively low recursion limit of 1000.

Comment: Yup. But this program can't harness this limit.

Comment: @Jens This worked. It was forcing the n to be a decimal which was always greater than zero leading to an infinite loop. Floor division worked :)